# How to configure a web app in tomcat 9 so it can use a H2 database?

Tags: clojure

I've build a web app in Clojure that uses an H2 database. I created a war file and deployed this to Apache Tomcat 9 to the webapps folder. Tomcat does recognize it because a folder with the name of the war file is created.

When trying to start the web app via the Tomcat manager i get an error due to the fact that it can't find the driver for the database:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:/somefolder/myDB.db`

It is showing the correct path to my database

When I run the web app using `lein repl` it works fine

I checked the war file for h2 and in WEB-INF/lib there is a h2-2.1.214.jar available

Can it be related to access rights in the folder where the database is located?

Comment: Is the war fully extracted in the webapps folder? might be a setting, so
the container does not need to, but if it tries, it should succeed.  But
then again you would see an error in the logs (which I assume, you have
checked)